# 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests when using rerunner-jupiter extension in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit5

I am trying to repeat selected tests if they fail using [rerunner-jupiter](https://github.com/artsok/rerunner-jupiter) extension. It works fine inside IntelliJ IDEA but fails on Jenkins with this message,

```
org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable

WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.support.filter.ClasspathScanningSupport.buildClassFilter(Lorg/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryRequest;Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)Lorg/junit/platform/commons/util/ClassFilter;
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:49)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.TestPlanScannerFilter.accept(TestPlanScannerFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.scanClasspath(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Jun 28, 2018 3:22:16 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
```

No tests are executed at all, whole test suite fails right in the beginning.

Comment: Looks like there are incompatible versions of `junit-platform-engine` and `juint-jupiter-engine` on your classpath. How do you run your tests? Maven? If so, could you please post the relevant parts of the POM?

Comment: Good hint, thanks. I found that jupiter and platform versions in my test project are 5.1.0, and 1.1.0 respectively, and those in the rerunner-jupiter's POM file are 5.0.0 and 1.0.0

Comment: So it works for you now?

Comment: I got it working by directly including sources from the extension into my project. There is still another issue. I have set repeat count to 3. My test fails first time, passes second time and third try is skipped, perfectly as expected. But Jenkins considers it as three tests and the job is marked as unstable due to one failure. I expect the job to be successful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could get message "TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests" in case you are running your code as named java9 module and you missed to require some dependencies in your `module-info.java`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801052/1874113