# TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests - Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector resolution failed

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

I am having an issue running my Integration Test.

As part of my Test, I use `exec-maven-plugin` to pull down other projects from source control and then run them locally so my Test can use that to perform against.

My Maven dependencies for JUnit are:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
            <useModulePath>false</useModulePath>
            <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I have created a profile called `integration-test` so that I can choose when to enable integration testing and also added an argument to `maven-surefire-plugin` called `skipUTs` so I can skip Unit Tests.

The output of running: `mvn clean verify -Pintegration-test -DskipUTs=true`

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:67)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.TestPlanScannerFilter.accept(TestPlanScannerFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.scanClasspath(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = 'com.farmlandbee.app.integration.IntegrationTest'] resolution failed
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:82)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:103)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotationCache(Class.java:2535)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Class.java:2221)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:128)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.determineDisplayName(DisplayNameUtils.java:68)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.<init>(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.<init>(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:94)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.<init>(ClassTestDescriptor.java:51)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.newClassTestDescriptor(ClassSelectorResolver.java:119)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$0(ClassSelectorResolver.java:71)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver$$Lambda$61/0000000000000000.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution$DefaultContext.createAndAdd(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:246)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution$DefaultContext.addToParent(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:209)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:134)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution$$Lambda$47/0000000000000000.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:514)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:501)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:487)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:241)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:185)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:91)
    ... 16 more
```

Test Class is roughly:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class,
        webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import({SSLRestTemplateConfig.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"integration"})
public class IntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Spy
    private final Service Service;

    private final IQueue<String> queue;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<String> captor;

    @Autowired
    public IntegrationTest(RestTemplate restTemplate,
                                Service service,
                                HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.service = accountingQueueService;
        this.queue = hazelcastInstance.getQueue("queue");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        queue.clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void IntegrationTest() throws InterruptedException {
        ...
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do your tests classes have the `@Test` annotation?

Comment: @hfontanez Yeah they do, I'll update question

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900637/error-testengine-with-id-junit-vintage-failed-to-discover-tests-with-spring. That should help you solve this issue.

Comment: @hfontanez I've looked at that already, that's a jackson error and for `junit-vintage`

Comment: Are you having this issue when launching your tests from an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ? There are configuration on the IDE you must do for JUnit.

Comment: It works when running the test from Intellij and if I run `mvn failsafe:integration-test`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228800/discussion-between-hfontanez-and-farmlandbee).

Comment: @farmlandbee could you share the full pom.xml file?

Comment: Please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, just a minimal project reproducing the issue.

Comment: @farmlandbee I found this and I don't know if you tried it already https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/625

Comment: You should really create and share a small example showing this behavior for others to examine if you want a good answer.  Right now this is pure guesswork.  Also you might be lucky that in the process of creating the small example you will find the solution yourself

Comment: @farmlandbee did you share your code on GitHub as suggested by kriegaex? I think that would be best.

Comment: Could you maven with -X parameter and trace where the exception happend. Additionally you can check in your `target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations/` the annotations classes are created.

Comment: I fixed this problem by changing the junit scope in my pom.xml from test to compile then re-running it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this problem too. I solved it by removing all JUnit libraries from IntelliJ / Project Structure / Libraries, and then compiling the project, failing, having IntelliJ resolve this by importing the latest version of JUnit.

I'm now on JUnit 5.9.1

I believe the culprit was junit-platform-commons which is now on 1.9.1

I got the idea from this JUnit 5 issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2881

Comment: Thanks Roger, this fixed it for me. My advice is to use the junit-bom to make sure all your dependency versions are aligned; junit5 has lots of modules.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem would lie in one of the following areas. I don't think there's enough information to nail it down, but I wanted to give you all the avenues to explore and it's too much to put in one big comment.

I have listed them in order of complexity.

1. You haven't set up your custom integration tests fully

There is information relevant that may help you configure your profiles and utilize them here: [Spring-boot default profile for integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690094/spring-boot-default-profile-for-integration-tests)

2. The @ActiveProfiles indicates a profile name of "integration" but your profile name is "integration-test"

If this is it, then just update the annotation to be integration-test and you're done.

3. The configuration of one of your annotations is incorrect or the classpath is incorrectly setup to allow the annotation to be recognized.

I am not familiar with how a display name generator is chosen, but there is one line that stands out to me as the closest complaining point to review. The line in the stack trace is:
org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.determineDisplayName(DisplayNameUtils.java:68)

I believe this is the correct code that backs this line: http://www.howsoftworks.net/junjupen/DisplayNameUtils#determineDisplayName-AnnotatedElement-Supplier

It appears to be evaluating the entire class for annotations to try to pull back this one. However, above you have no DisplayName annotation configured, so I don't think it's a problem with DisplayName, but with one of the others.

Looking further in the stack, it looks like it's attempting to utilize/cache the Annotations of the class itself. This may lead to the annotations cache evaluating ALL entries on the class at this point and displayName is just the first one being requested.

In that case, it's possible it's tripping up on one of your OTHER annotations that you simply haven't configured correctly. ArrayStore exception makes me wonder if you've put an element where an array should be or vice-versa.

However, researching further, it looks like this error (line 724 in AnnotationParser) relates to a suite of JDK issues that were properly fixed in one of the JDK-11 releases. It is indicated in other places as a "sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy".

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-7183985

The gist of these bugs have to do with an Annotation referencing a class that's not in the classpath (the Type is not present). This is probably what's going on with one of your annotations in your configuration but from the posted information it's unlikely we can advise which one.

Upgrading to a JDK where this is fixed would likely help you better pinpoint the root problem by reporting a better error for you with specific missing type information. If that's an option, you can choose to do that, too.

The root problem is likely that your new profile environment leads to a misconfiguration that's accidentally excluding a class that you need for the annotations on your test to be coherent.

Comment: This is pretty good information. I'm not sure if this will fix the OPs issue since he hasn't responded, but I'm going to award you the bounty anyway.

Comment: Thank you for awarding. I hope it helps! I'm very curious for OP to respond too and confirm if it did.

Comment: @hfontanez By the time this answer was submitted, I had left to go to a new company.  I really like the answer though.

Comment: Glad to help and also close the chapter on this actually being useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the profile via command like this :

```
mvn clean verify -Dspring.profiles.active=integration-test
```

Comment: Alejandro, I am looking for a canonical answer. In essence, the OP is looking for an answer, and I am interesting in a slightly different answer because my problem, although related, it is not the same and thus requires a deeper understanding of the root cause in order for me to fix my issue. If you can expand on your answer, that might be what we both are looking for. This link should help you understand what a canonical answer is: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/2851311

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way is  to click  File->InvalidateCaches/Restart...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually when the classpath contains multiple versions of junit

for ex.  `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2` and `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0` both of which are incompatible with one another.

or for ex. both junit4 and junit5 libraries are on the classpath together.

To check if this is the case, do a `gradlew dependecies --configuration testCompileClasspath` (if you are using gradle. maven would have something similar) to check the dependency tree for multiple versions.

Sometimes, spring boot might be interfering using its dependency management plugin. The way it messes up is it fixes the version of junit in the dependency tree, no matter what version you have declared. So you might have one of the junit jars declared explicitly with one version and spring will be pulling another version.

Either ways, the dependency tree is the best way to find the problem. Once you get the version to be in sync, and everything will be fine.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, you need to ensure that the dependency version that you are using is compatible with the Java version that you are using. I was getting the same error. I had updated the `junit-jupiter` to `5.9.0` but I was using Java 11 due to which I was getting this error. On changing Java version to Java 17, the tests started running.