# Cannot resolve symbol Suite for junit.platform.suite.api when using Spring parent annotation

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit5, spring-test

I'm trying to update our project from JUnit4 to JUnit5, but I get this error with the imports.

[image]

I think the issue is to do with using spring parent. If I remove that from my debug branch it'll work.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

However, there may be a way to keep both?

I tried excluding the JUnit platform-suite-engine from spring test but that didn't work.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my complete pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hmhco</groupId>
    <artifactId>vcservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
    <name>My Service</name>
    <description>My Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you’re using the wrong artefact. Should be junit-platform-suite-engine.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that would have made sense. However, although now I see two options when I type rather than one as before, I'm afraid I still don't see the one I need. I'll update the post with the screenshot.

Comment: I think the error is to do with the spring parent annotation. It works if I remove that on a debug branch. I'll update the post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got someone to help me on a forum and adding this fixed the original issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, I still can't run the tests as I now get this other issue.

[image]

I've tried different combinations of JUnit versions as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900637/error-testengine-with-id-junit-vintage-failed-to-discover-tests-with-spring) but I can't make it work. I guess though that would be a different issue so I can close this post as resolved.

Comment: My issue was the same as yours, this solved my problem and my tests are still working, but my Suite is not able to recognize the tests (although this might be because of another problem I might have, I'm configuring a Suite for the first time)