# Test suite migration from JUnit4 to JUnit5

Tags: java, maven, junit5, test-suite

I've migrated all the JUnit tests in my project from version 4 to version 5.
The project is composed by severals Maven modules and projects like the following architecture

- parent pom

  - backend project
  - core project

    - some modules
    - test suite module

      - **TestSuite.java**
  - ... some other projects

Inside the TestSuite.java, I had the following code under Junit4

```
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite;
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite.ClassnameFilters;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@ClassnameFilters({"common.package.of.all.projects.*"})
public class TestSuite {
   
}
```

Now I try to create the equivalent configuration under JUnit5

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@SelectPackages("common.package.of.all.projects.*")
public class TestSuite {
    
}
```

And this is an extract of the test suite module **pom.xml**

```
// this lib help to execute the test suite under eclipse
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.takari.junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>takari-cpsuite</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
// these are the test dependencies I added
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 // all module are in the dependencies like the following
 <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>module.name</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
```

I use IntelliJ IDE and JDK 17.0.5,
**But when I try to run the test suite, none of the tests are launched. It seems like there are not found despite I added the modules in the *dependenciesToScan***
Here is the warning I get

```
WARNING: Third-party TestEngine implementations are forbidden to use the reserved 'junit-' prefix for their ID: 'junit-platform-suite'
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-platform-suite' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.parentConfigurationParameters(org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters)'
    at org.junit.platform.suite.commons.SuiteLauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.build(SuiteLauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestDescriptor.discover(SuiteTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
```

As suggested in another post [Error "TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests" with Spring Boot 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900637/error-testengine-with-id-junit-vintage-failed-to-discover-tests-with-spring) about this warning, I added an exclusion for junit.vintage in the parent pom for spring-boot-starter-test

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

So I'm probably missing something in my configuration or maybe it is not the right way to achieve what I want.
Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Why do you need to scan dependencies? Sounds like those "Suites" are integration tests? So maybe better go with naming `*IT` and using failsafe-plugin instead??? Why do you need test suites? Is using the general unit test approach (`*Test.java`) and as mentioned `*IT.java`not enough?

Comment: I don't know, the project existed before I came on it. Maybe this part is not needed anymore, all the tests are like *Test.java. Maybe if I succeed to run them without the dependencies scan I'd remove that part

Comment: First do you use spring-boot-parent ? Or are you going via BOM file (spring-boot-dependencies)? Best would be having a real example project on github or alike... because there are so many information missing...

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the `junit-platform-suite-engine` as well as `junit-jupiter-engine` as a dependency.

They are both needed to run suites with JUnit Jupiter.

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Ok I tried it. I get the same result but there is now a warning saying WARNING: Third-party TestEngine implementations are forbidden to use the reserved 'junit-' prefix for their ID: 'junit-platform-suite'

Comment: Please show your full pom file and show the commands you are using furthermore the JDK version, Maven version etc... and the full error output...

Comment: I edited the question with more info about the pom/JDK and the full warning output. The maven version is 3.8.6